# Issue to run curl command in windows 7 Docker Quickstart Terminal

Tags: curl, virtualbox, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, docker-toolbox

I am trying out the steps for setting up a sample hyperledger fabric1.0 network as per the steps mentioned [**here**](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) on windows 7. As part of this I am following these steps for [Hyperledger Fabric Samples](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html).

Since my OS is **Windows7 64bit**, I am using [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)

But my problem here is, while running the following command in ***Docker Quickstart Terminal***

> curl -sSL https://goo.gl/iX9dek ¦ bash

I am getting the error

> bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
>   
> bash: line 1: <HTML>

I also found a note in the steps like

> If you get an error running the above curl command, you may have too old a version of curl. Please visit the Prerequisites page for additional information on where to find the latest version.

I have the latest version of curl set in the windows environment, but in  ***Docker Quickstart Terminal*** it is using some older version. 
I tried to update it in virtual machine terminal using `yum update curl.x86_64` but *yum*, *update* etc. are not found.

How can I update the curl in this case? And if the curl version is not the problem, where I am doing wrong here?

Please suggest..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the issue.:)

The problem was with the url **https://goo.gl/iX9dek**, the document here is moved to 
[here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html) which is not updated in the [**stepout**](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html) that I am following.

It is working with the following command

> curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.0.sh | bash

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the issue is more likely that the version of curl on your machine doesn't support redirects. In the note below the [instructions](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#download-platform-specific-binaries) for the curl command is a note that suggests that if you have errors, [update your version of curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Note that replacing the URL with the raw GH URL is also a correct
solution, but you probably want to update curl regardless.

Comment: Yes you are right. But as mentioned in the post I couldn't update the curl version in the virtual machine since the commands I tried were not working(might be because I am less familiar with these commands).  That's why I tried with new url and fortunately it worked :). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582747/how-to-switch-from-docker-toolbox-curl-to-the-curl-defined-in-windows-path